# How to rollover image with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in js, I need to change several images at hover on the same imagine like this : http://www.revzilla.com/ on slider, any suggest?

thi is my html, in ct-image I have several images that move your mouse inside the container replaces  with the other imgs :

```html
<li class="product-primary clearfix">
  <a href="https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea">
    <div class="ct-image" style="background:url(imgs/product1.jpg)" data-image="imgs/product1.jpg" data-alt="">

      <div class="banner-new"><span>new</span>
        <p class="title-product-hidd">lorem</p>
      </div>
      <!--.banner-new-->
      <div class="banner-acti">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--.banner-acti-->
  </a>
  <!--effetto all'hover-->
  <div class="ct-hove">
    <div class="text-pro">
      <p class="text">I</p>
      <p class="text">I</p>
      <p class="tex">I</p>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="compare-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="buy-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="wishlist-icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!--.ct-hover-->

  <div class="ct-descript-prod-left">
    <p class="title-prod">Name</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
  </div>
  <!--.ct-descript-pro-bt-->
  <div class="ct-descript-prod-right">
    <h4>€ 0.000.00</h4>
    <ul>
      <li class="imgLink" data-target="#">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="imgLink" data-target="#">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--.ct-descript-pro-bt-->
</li>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to change several images at hover on the same"  you want to display multiple images at once on hover? or you need to create a slider?

Comment: like this, http://www.revzilla.com/, see the slider on the bottom, when you hover an image and move your mouse the imgs change, i need to replicate the same effect

Comment: Do you mean the slider with bike stuff? For me it only moves using the mouse wheel. In any case, either by hoovering or using the mouse wheel, you only need to attach the proper event handler and, using jquery, you can use the function `animate` (check the docs for the different parameters) to emulate that behaviour

Comment: not the slider, inside the slider the are some products, when you move you mouse inside the image-product it changes with another imgs..

Comment: Why don't you do that with css?

Comment: because it's all dynamic, so i have 200products,

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I have found for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  
  var flipImages = function($container) {
    var amount = $container.data("amount");
    var current = $container.data("current");
    
    if(current >= amount){
      current = 1;
    } else {
      current = current + 1;
    }

    var dataAttr = "image" + current;
    var image = $container.data(dataAttr);
    $container.fadeOut(200, function() {
      $container.css("background-image", "url(" + image + ")");
      $container.fadeIn(200);
      $container.data("current", current);
    });
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      flipImages($container);
    }, 1000)
  };

  $(".ct-image").hover(
    function() {
      var $that = $(this);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        flipImages($that);
      }, 1000)
    }, 
    function() {
      if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.ct-image {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ct-image" style="background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/300x300/00eb1b/fff)"
data-image1="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/00eb1b/fff"
data-image2="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/0c00eb/fff"
data-image3="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/eb8500/fff"
data-image4="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/eb0014/fff"
data-current="1"
data-amount="4">
<!-- your content-->
</div>
```

Note. Solution is without flipping animation. It requires change in structure of your code.

Comment: martin just 1 thing, but if i want stop the effect when the mouse it's stationery?  i try to change .hover with .mousemove but the event's not trigger, any suggest?

Comment: You should add additional event handler for mousemove - it should clear timeout for filpImages and start flipping when certain time passes (ie. 15 ms)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like that ?

```js
 $('.carousel').mouseleave(function(){
  var  currentActiveImage = $('.item-show');
  var  nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

  if(nextActiveImage.length == 0)
  {
   nextActiveImage = $(".carousel #item").first();
  }
  currentActiveImage.removeClass('item-show').addClass('item-hidden');
  nextActiveImage.addClass('item-show').removeClass('item-hidden');
 });
```

```css
.item-show {
  display: inline-block;
}
.item-hidden{
  display: none;
}

.info {
  position:absolute;
  top: 231px;
  left: 505px;
  background: grey;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div id="item" class="item-show">
    <img  src="http://www.bu.edu/khc/files/2012/09/Video11_700x300.jpg" />
    <div class="info">
      <span>some text</span>
      <p>Price: 88$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class="item-hidden">
    <img src="http://www.mezzolabs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/traffic-700x300.jpg" />
    <div class="info">
      <span>This is Cool</span>
      <p>Price: 99$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="item" class="item-hidden">
    <img  src="http://www.mezzolabs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/heaven-700x300.jpg"/>
    <div class="info">
      <span>This is train</span>
      <p>Price: 100$</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thx, but no, see revzilla.com i need solution like that, with my structure.